# Using sparklyr write SQL on new Spark Dataframe

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I am able to create a Spark dataframe using:

```
df_01 <- sdf_sql(sc, "select * from database.table")
```

How can I use `sparklyr` to access the created Spark dataframe df_01 in a subsequent SQL query? For example:

```
df_02 <- sdf_sql(sc, "select * from df_02")
```

Note that SparkR is a library that I do not have access to so I cannot use the following:

```
createOrReplaceTempView(people, "people")

teenagers <- sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
head(teenagers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`sdf_register`](https://spark.rstudio.com/packages/sparklyr/latest/reference/sdf_register.html) function from Sparklyr.

```
df_01 <- sdf_sql(sc, "select * from database.table")
sdf_register(df_01, "sdf_table_01")
df_02 <- sdf_sql(sc, "select * from sdf_table_01")
```